# White/Blank screen on iOS device, but work just fine on Simulator and Android

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a Flutter app that is almost just the basic Android Studio template. When I run the app on the Android emulator or the iOS simulator it works just fine and displays my widgets, and when I make a release build for Android it also works just fine, but when I make a release build for iOS and run it on a iPhone I am only seeing a white/blank screen with no widgets displayed. I have googled this and tried with flutter clean before my build but I can not figure out why this is happening. Please any ideas here?

I have now also tried running on the device from the XCode workspace, there I also get a white/blank screen and this in the console log:

```
2019-06-25 11:10:43.248687+0200 Runner[513:22949] Failed to find snapshot: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B27448A1-A487-44FC-B6F7-CCFBDFCBB0AD/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
2019-06-25 11:10:43.533596+0200 Runner[513:22949] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2019-06-25 11:10:43.533634+0200 Runner[513:22949] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2019-06-25 11:10:43.538915+0200 Runner[513:23047] [VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(115)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
2019-06-25 11:10:43.539130+0200 Runner[513:23047] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterEngine.mm(304)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
2019-06-25 11:10:43.539359+0200 Runner[513:23071] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51568/Vcbbvx3tfNI=/
```

I have ziped my entire project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8olmovqjquxveg/thisisit.zip?dl=0

Thank you
Søren

Comment: please go product>scheme>Edit Schema and select Build Configuration "Release".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to delete the ios folder and recreate it by calling "flutter create" on the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

please go product>scheme>Edit Schema
and select Build Configuration "Release"

[image]

and then

[image]

Comment: Same result, I added some log output from xcode to my question.

Comment: please run the " flutter build ios" and then restart your xcode and check the scheme

Answer (score 0):

React-native =>
First Paste Code In AppDelegate

```
#if DEBUG
// return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"] //[RNGoogleSignin application:application openURL:url options:options];
#endif
}
```

If you are using provison_profile in xcode for creating build then check provison_profile in appledeveloper account that is valid or not, if not valid then click on this and edit provison_profile & save and donwload & install in your mac.

Now you can create build.